# Error installing module with pip on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, pip, kivy, python-module, python-3.5

I have trouble installing modules using pip, for example

```
sudo -H pip3 install kivy
```

returns this error

```
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-b3rwh_e6/kivy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bev6v2mx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-b3rwh_e6/kivy/
```

I am fairly new to python and to programming in general so I'm probably doing something wrong, it's probably worth mentioning that I have python2.7 and python3.5 installed, and installing the packages `python3.5-dev` and `build-essential` didn't fix it.

Edit: build log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5e3GD1lfCbUZ19LU3RENzY4MU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the full build log.

Comment: Did you read through the build log? It clearly shows that several packages are missing. Did you attempt to install them?

Answer (score 1):

Packages which include C extensions require compilation and so might require both gcc and python-dev (and in some cases gcc-c++).

run:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev
```

prior to pip installing your package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

for python2.7 ?

From the official site

https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

for python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

for python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

Comment: It was already installed, and I don't generally use python2.7 generally I keep it because of dependencies